# Configuring default output format of aws cli in shell script

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

Iam writing a shell script in which I am configuring awscli. The container in which the script whill be running has the default output format as json. I have to change the output format to text when I run the script in the method.

I have written below function in shell but doesn't works

```
function awsConfigure(){
    echo "configuring aws cli"
    aws configure set aws_access_key_id *************
    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key **********
    aws configure set default.region us-east-2
    aws configure output text


}
```

How can I set the text format in this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `aws configure set output text`.